# how to create different UI components every times in runtime and save their contents into database and save the UI which created on the page?

Tags: oracle-adf

Dears
good day
I need your help for the following case:
The activity nature of the client is very dynamic 
Need to have a dynamic form (he wants to create many form every day by himself in runtime). And add some components in the runtime.
He doesn't have a standard form so he need every day to create new form
For example he can make today a form with group of input text and group of check box and table and tomorrow he need to make a new form with input text and radio and table also etc..,.
In addition he needs to achieve and save it into database to use it and retrieve it later , and he wants to save every form with its UI contents which he created in runtime to be able to view it later on the jsf page.
So he want to save created form contains data into database 
And also he wants to arrange the component on the page by his own way
And I putted this case in OTN :

https://community.oracle.com/message/14356236#14356236 
How could I do it?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can find a series of blog posts of Andrejus, right here:

http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/adf-12c-dynamic-forms-with-adf-bc-ui.html

Comment: Thanks Florin for your attention .. I saw this article before but it's not recover my case ... Thanks a lot